# is there any way to white label MAUI app?

Tags: xamarin.forms, maui, white-labelling

I have project in Xamarin forms which we have to migrate to .NET MAUI we need White Labelling in that project like this [White Labeling in Xamarin Forms Applications](https://xamgirl.com/white-labeling-in-xamarin-forms-applications/)

In Xamarin forms I define constants and configuration in solution and project file and set info.plist and android manifest file. when I build project it is picking file according to configuration.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Does #IF work?

Comment: You can apply a lot, if not all, of what is described in that blog post but in a slightly different way to .NET MAUI. So the answer is: yes, you can white label .NET MAUI apps.

Comment: One option is to whitelabel your app by using standard #IF commands to the selected items. A 2nd option is to have at the same folder a 2nd .proj file where you will include various assets and xaml files that are different between your project.
A 3rd more clear option is to have the common files to a separate folder, and different .proj file for easy flavour.

Comment: What exactly will be changed from one customer to another?  If you're just changing icons and strings like company name then the way I'd do that is with resource dictionaries in Wpf. Looks to me like it'd work in Maui. You'd presumably have a build mechanism per customer and substitute files using a ci/cd pipeline transparent to the app code.

Comment: In Xamarin forms I define constants and configuration in solution and project file and set info.plist and android manifest file. when I build project it is picking file according to configuration. @GeraldVersluis